# RESTRequest returns error while working with HMRC Tax Platform

Tags: delphi, rest-client

I'm working on "2. Exchange the OAuth 2.0 authorisation code for an access token" of the `HMRC Tutorial /hello/user`.

I've managed to get the Authorization Code but when running the following code:

```
{$REGION '1. Get the the Authorisation Code'}
wv := Tfrm_OAuthWebForm.Create(self);
try
  wv.OnAfterRedirect := OAuth2Authenticator1_Hello_User_Redirect;
  wv.ShowModalWithURL(LURL);
finally
  wv.Release;
end;
{$ENDREGION '1. Get the the Authorisation Code'}
```

1.HM Revenue & Customs. Authority to interact with HMRC on your behalf. Click Continue.
2.HM Revenue & Customs. Sing In. User ID and Password. Sign In.
3.Click Grant Access.
4.Issued the Authorization Code in the code on the `OAuth2Authenticator1_Hello_User_Redirect Event`.
5.Display my Redirect Page.
6.Close the `Tfrm_OAuthWebForm`.

Following code is the executed:

```
RESTClient1.Authenticator := OAuth2Authenticator1_Hello_User;
RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://test-api.service.hmrc.gov.uk/oauth/token';
RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('grant_type', 'authorization_code', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('client_id', eHello_User_Client_ID.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('client_secret', eHello_User_Client_Secret.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('redirect_uri', eHello_User_Redirect.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('authorization_code', eHello_User_Authorization_Code.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
RESTRequest1.Execute;
```

An Exception is raised when calling the `RESTRequest1.Execute`.

```
procedure TfrmMain.RESTRequest1HTTPProtocolError(Sender: TCustomRESTRequest);
begin
// show error
  Add_To_Memo(Sender.Response.StatusText, False{Clear_Memo});
  Add_To_Memo(Sender.Response.Content, False{Clear_Memo});
  // Sender.Response.Content, = <!--[if lt IE 9]><html class="no-js lte-ie8"
end;
```

The `Sender.Response.StatusText` is

> Not Found

The `Sender.Response.Content` is

> HMRC Tax Platform - Page not found - 404
>   [image: HMRC Page not Found 404]

HMRC say

> in the 400 to 499 range if it didn't succeed because of a client error by your application

I've check and re check the application but can see what's upsetting the code when passing the Authorization Code to Get the Access & Refresh Tokens.

Using the same OAuth2Authenticator I:
1.Right Mouse click the OAuth2Authenticator.
2.Select Configure.
3.Press Authorize.
4.Enter the User Id and Password.
5.Click Grant Access.
6.I get issued a Access Token and Refresh Token with no errors.

Any ideas what I'm missing in my code?

Hope that makes sense.
TIA

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404 *Page not found* seems pretty much self-explanatory; the page you've asked for wasn't found. Can you open that page in your web browser?

Comment: Hi Ken, thanks for the reply. I've copied the "Sender.Response.Content" and saved as a HTML (image of page is in main question). My question is what have I done wrong? Anyone else tried the HMRC Tax Tutorial Hello/User with success?